# While trying to use argv[1] in C I get a segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 1000
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 2 || (isdigit(argv[1])) != 1 ){
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key");
        exit(1);
    }else{
        int j=atoi(argv[1]);
        int i=0;
        char c[MAX];
        printf("plaintext:  ");
        fgets(c, MAX, stdin);
        int k=strlen(c);
        for(i=0;i<k;i++){
            if(c[i] >= 97 && c[i] <= 122){
                if(c[i] + j > 122){
                }
            }
            }
        }
        return 0;

}
```

This is like a basic encryption code(incomplete because it would not be useful to include the full code imo). when this runs it immediately returns a segmentation fault.

Comment: also i forgot to mention that when I remove the argv[1] from the code it does not give any segmentation faults. And yes I did use the input from the command line correctly(./code 15), for example

Comment: [isdigit](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isdigit) takes an `int` but you are passing it a `char *`. If that isn't it then do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger and find out exactly where it crashes and what it is accessing at that point.

Comment: `isdigit(argv[1])` hmm.... what is `argv[1]` ? A character?

Comment: Please enable compiler warnings! You are passing the wrong type to `isdigit()`. Anyway, it's a mistake to compare `isdigit` with `1`. If passed a digit character, a **non-zero** value is returned.

Comment: Add `*(int *)` in front of argv[1]. so that isdigit syntax will be like : `isdigit(*(int *)argv[1])`.

Comment: @AayushShah That's not good advice. `argv[1]` is a `char *`. Dereferencing it as an `int *` will not get the desired result.

Comment: @AayushShah function `isdigit` takes *one* character expressed as unsigned integer. That will consider the first *four* characters (if 32-bit int). It needs to be `!isdigit(argv[1][0])`

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: Don't use `97` and `122` where you could use `'a'` and `'z'` to make things clearer (or even `islower()` given that you include `<ctype.h>`).

Comment: You also can't assume `isdigit` will always return `1` for true.  Just remove the comparison entirely, leaving it as `|| isdigit(...)`.

Comment: Don't forget that `fgets` also read the end of line character `\n` that you probably want to remove before encrypting.